# Uploading a file to Chrome using Selenium (or any other way) on mac iOS

Tags: java, ios, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, upload

I'm using Selenium, Chrome and mac iOS

I thought uploading a file from my machine to browser (facebook site) would be trivial, but appereantely it's not

Is there a way (using Selenium or any other framework) to upload one file from my machine to browser (facebook website)

I tried sendkeys(),  AWT Robot class, I also tried drag and drop using Selenium, but nothing works for me.

Any ideas or thoughts ? ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try a Robot class.

Robot rbt=new Robot();

r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
      //releasing enter
      r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
      //pressing ctrl+v
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
      r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
```

Comment: If I'll use Robot, I'll have other problem: once the file picker is opened I can't get focus on that file picker module.   Is there a know issue uploading file using Selenium on mac ? (maybe on security aspects? )